# Use Residue Theorem to Sum Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> Show that
>   $$\sum_{n=- \infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(3n-1)^2} = \frac{4 \pi^2}{27}$$

I'm pretty sure I need to use the Residue Theorem to sum the series, but I'm unsure how to apply it. Here's what I know:

- There is a double pole at $3n-1=0 \Rightarrow n= \frac{1}{3}$
- $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} f(n) = -\sum$ of the resides of $ \pi \cot( \pi z) \cdot f(z)$ at the pole(s) of $f(z)$

Using the above information, here's what I've done to calculate the residue at $z= \frac{1}{3}$ so far:
$$ \frac{1}{(2-1)!}\lim_{z\to\frac{1}{3}} \Bigg[ \frac{d^{2-1}}{dz^{2-1}} \Bigg((z- \frac{1}{3}) \pi \cot( \pi z) \frac{1}{{(3z-1)}^2} \Bigg) \Bigg]$$

$$= \Bigg(\lim_{z\to\frac{1}{3}} \frac{d}{dz} \pi \cot (\pi z)\Bigg) \Bigg(\lim_{z\to\frac{1}{3}} \frac{d}{dz} \frac{z-\frac{1}{3}}{(3z-1)^2}\Bigg) $$ 
$$= \Bigg( \lim_{z\to\frac{1}{3}} {- \pi^2 \csc({\pi z})} \Bigg) \Bigg( \lim_{z\to\frac{1}{3}} \frac{1}{(3z-1)^2}\Bigg)$$

But 
$$\lim_{z\to\frac{1}{3}} \frac{1}{(3z-1)^2}= \infty$$

I know I've gone wrong somewhere (maybe when I split it up into two limits?), but I'm not sure where. Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: At a pole $z_0$ of $g$ of order $k > 0$, you need $$\biggl(\frac{d}{dz}\biggr)^{k-1}\bigl( (z - z_0)^k\cdot g(z)\bigr).$$ You used $(z - z_0)^1$ instead.

Comment: But, for this series, you can have it easier. For $n > 1$, you get $\frac{1}{2^2},\, \frac{1}{5^2},\, \frac{1}{8^2},\,\dotsc$, and for $n \leqslant 0$ you get $\frac{1}{(-1)^2},\, \frac{1}{(-4)^2},\, \frac{1}{(-7)^2},\,\dotsc$. Since $(-(3k+1))^2 = (3k+1)^2$, if you add, what's the difference to $\sum_{m =  1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m^2} = \zeta(2)$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Got it. Silly mistake. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This question was already asked earlier yesterday o the day before. You don't need complex theory to solve this, yet you need, at least with my method, to know that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$$

Answer (score 0):

Your sum $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(3n-1)^2}$$ is no different from $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(3n)^2}.$$  Now using user26535 $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ we can gather that your sum is the same as $(1-\frac{1}{9})\frac{\pi^2}{6}$.